# Rails, mock object in module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I've been trying to test my helper module in rails, and in one of the methods, I calling rails `request` object. But it seems incorrect, and it doesn't work properly.

How I can to mock `request` object in the right way? thank you.

**Example:**

```
module MyHelper
  def get_header
    request.headers['My-header']
  end
end
```

and tests look like.

```
RSpec.describe MyHelper do
  include MyHelper

  it 'should fetch header' do
    allow(:request).to receive(:headers).and_return(headers: { 'My-header' => 'my-header-value' })
    expect(get_header).to eq 'my-header-value'
  end
end
```

An error of the test

```
 Failure/Error: allow(:request).to receive(:headers).and_return(headers: { 'My-header' => 'my-header-value' })

     TypeError:
       can't define singleton
```

Comment: what error are u getting? what do you mean by "it doesn't work properly"?

Comment: @TamerShlash I've updated the question, it doesn't work properly" --- it doesn't substitute the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. It should be `request` not `:request`

Try

```
allow(request).to receive(:headers).and_return(headers: { 'My-header' => 'my-header-value' })
```

> the request object is nil

The method you have stubbed will return `headers: { 'My-header' => 'my-header-value' }`. But you are trying to access without accessing the key `:headers`.

Try the below:

```
it 'should fetch header' do
  allow(request).to receive(:headers).and_return('My-header' => 'my-header-value')
  expect(get_headers).to eq 'my-header-value'
end
```

Comment: hm, without success, the `request` object is nil;(

Comment: maybe this `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` if assing true for this option, maybe it will help, but I'm not sure that is correct.